# how to update or add values during runtime in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am learning Oracle database and I was wondering if values could be updated or added dynamically to a table during execution of a procedure.

when I execute my code the problem is that it asks for the value of dis upon creation of procedure and on execution, it assigns that value to only the first row.

```
create or replace procedure update_dist as

 dis number;

begin
 for i in 1..7 loop
    dis:=&dis;
    dbms_output.put_line(i);
    update ride_detail set r_dist=dis where rownum=i;
 end loop;
 end; 
 /
```

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems:

1. A substitution variable will be replaced when the command is executed. Your command is `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ...` and so the substitution variable will be replaced in the DDL statement to give a static value (and not every time the procedure is run).
2. You cannot use `WHERE ROWNUM=i` for values where `i > 1` as rows are only assigned a `ROWNUM` when they match the filter conditions so the first row to be read will be checked to see if `ROWNUM = 2` (for example) but its the first row so it will be discarded and then the second row read will be tested for `ROWNUM = 2` but, because the first row didn't match the filter conditions then this second row will also have `ROWNUM` of `1` and `1 != 2` so it will be discarded as well ... repeat ad-nauseum and all the rows will not match your filter.

If you want to pass in dynamic values then pass them as input values:

```sql
create or replace procedure update_dist(
  value1 IN RIDE_DETAIL.R_DIST%TYPE,
  value2 IN RIDE_DETAIL.R_DIST%TYPE,
  value3 IN RIDE_DETAIL.R_DIST%TYPE,
  value4 IN RIDE_DETAIL.R_DIST%TYPE,
  value5 IN RIDE_DETAIL.R_DIST%TYPE,
  value6 IN RIDE_DETAIL.R_DIST%TYPE,
  value7 IN RIDE_DETAIL.R_DIST%TYPE,
)
as
begin
  MERGE INTO ride_detail dst
  USING (
    SELECT r.rid, d.value
    FROM   ( SELECT ROWID  AS rid,
                    ROWNUM AS rn  -- assign ROWNUM without filtering
             FROM   ride_detail
           ) r
           INNER JOIN
           ( SELECT 1 AS rn, value1 AS value FROM DUAL UNION ALL
             SELECT 2 AS rn, value2 AS value FROM DUAL UNION ALL
             SELECT 3 AS rn, value3 AS value FROM DUAL UNION ALL
             SELECT 4 AS rn, value4 AS value FROM DUAL UNION ALL
             SELECT 5 AS rn, value5 AS value FROM DUAL UNION ALL
             SELECT 6 AS rn, value6 AS value FROM DUAL UNION ALL
             SELECT 7 AS rn, value7 AS value FROM DUAL
           ) d
           ON ( r.rn = d.rn )
  ) src
  ON ( src.rid = dst.ROWID )
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET r_dist = src.value;
END; 
/
```